# 'unsupported_grant_type' when trying to get an access token from Discord API

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

So I am trying to implement Discord login to my website, but when trying to exchange the code for an access token from `https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token` I just get `{ error: 'unsupported_grant_type' }`.

My code:

```
        const tokenResponseData = await request('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                client_id: config.clientId,
                client_secret: config.clientSecret,
                code: code,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                redirect_uri: `http://localhost:3000/api/auth`,
                scope: 'identify',
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        });
```

Been struggling with this for a while now, so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was doing it all wrong. I needed to have the request parameters formatted like URL queries and sent as a string in the body of the POST request.

```js
const tokenResponseData = await fetch(
  `https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token`,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: `client_id=${encodeURIComponent(`${config.clientId}`)}&client_secret=${encodeURIComponent(`${config.clientSecret}`)}&grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(`http://localhost:3000/api/auth`)}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/645) on the Discord GitHub, this can happen when your body is incorrectly formatted.

After some digging, I saw [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380843/oauth-unsupported-grant-type-discord-api) which has led me to believe that you should use URLSearchParams rather than stringifying your json data.

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('client_id', config.clientId);
params.append('client_secret', config.clientSecret);
params.append('code', code);
params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
params.append('redirect_uri', `http://localhost:3000/api/auth`);
params.append('scope', 'identify');

const tokenResponseData = await request(
    'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        data: params,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting your body? It does seem like most issues related to this are rooted from an improperly formatted body in your request.

Comment: I have tried everything I found on Google, JSON.stringifying the body, URLSearchParams, undici and node-fetch and nothing has fixed it.